# Stored Procedure returns results in Sql correctly but not in C# using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageSubscribers] 
(
    [SubscriberId]     INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SubscriberCode]   NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [SubscriberName]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [SubscriberActiveDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [SubscriberExpiryDate] DATETIME NULL,
    [SubscriberEndpoint]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [TopicId]              INT NOT NULL,
    [EventId]              INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MessageSubscribers] PRIMARY KEY ([SubscriberId])
);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchSubscriberDetails_BasedonTopicEvent]
    @eventid int,
    @topicid int,
    @subscribers NVARCHAR(max) = null
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

    /** Fetching Subscriber Details for all Subscribers based on Topic and Event**/
   SELECT DISTINCT  
       s.SubscriberCode, s.SubscriberName,
       s.SubscriberActiveDate, s.SubscriberExpiryDate,
       s.SubscriberEndpoint
   FROM
       ([dbo].[MessageSubscribers] s 
   WHERE 
       s.TopicId = @topicid 
       AND s.EventId = @eventid
       AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN s.SubscriberActiveDate AND ISNULL(s.SubscriberExpiryDate,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
       AND (s.SubscriberCode IS NULL OR s.SubscriberCode = '' 
            OR s.SubscriberCode IN (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@subscribers, ',')))
END
```

Sample data:

```
SubscriberId -- 1
SubscriberCode --   100
Subscriber Name --  Google
ActiveDate --   01-01-2022
ExpiryDate  -- NULL
Endpoint --     https://..1
TopicId --  1
EventId --  1

SubscriberId -- 2
SubscriberCode --   200
Subscriber Name --  Microsoft
ActiveDate --   01-01-2022
ExpiryDate  -- NULL
Endpoint --     https://..2
TopicId --  1
EventId --  1

SubscriberId -- 3
SubscriberCode -- NULL
Subscriber Name --  Wipro
ActiveDate --   01-01-2022
ExpiryDate  -- NULL
Endpoint --     https://..3
TopicId --  1
EventId --  1
```

C# code:

```
public async Task<List<Subscriber>> Fetch_SubscribersDetails(int topicid, int eventid, string subscribers)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Fetch_SubscribersDetails: Started -- Retrieving Subscriber details  from database based on topicid: {topicid}, eventid: {eventid} subscribers: {subscribers}.");

    List<Subscriber> subscribersDetails = new List<Subscriber>();
    subscribersDetails.Clear();

    try
    {
        string sqlconnectionString = SharedMethods.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sbstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sqlconnectionString);
        sbstr.Password = SharedMethods.GetEnvironmentVariable("DbSQLPassword");

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sbstr.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = Constants.FetchSubscribersbasedonTopicEventStorProcName;

            // Setting command timeout to 1 minute
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //cmd.Parameters.Add($"@topicid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = topicid;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add($"@eventid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eventid;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add($"@subscribers", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = subscribers.Trim();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@topicid", topicid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@eventid", eventid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@subscribers", subscribers.Trim());

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            await conn.OpenAsync();

            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            if (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                //subscribersDetails = await GenerateSubscribersDataAsync(reader);

                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();

                    subscriber.SubscriberCode = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberCode")));
                    subscriber.SubscriberEndpoint = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberEndpoint")));
                    subscriber.SubscriberName = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberName")));
                    subscriber.TopicName = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("TopicName")));
                    subscriber.EventName = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("EventName")));
                    subscriber.SubscriberActiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberActiveDate")));

                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberExpiryDate")))
                    {
                        subscriber.SubscriberExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberExpiryDate")));
                    }

                    subscribersDetails.Add(subscriber);
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation($"Fetch_SubscribersDetails: Completed -- Retrieving Subscriber details  from database based on topicid: {topicid}, eventid: {eventid} subscribers: {subscribers} , TotalSubscribers: {subscribersDetails.Count}.");

            return subscribersDetails;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Message: {ex.Message}. \nInnerException:{ex.InnerException}. \nStackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}. \nInnerExceptionMessage:{ex.InnerException?.Message}.");
        subscribersDetails = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         subscribersDetails = null;
         _logger.LogError($"Message: {ex.Message}. \nInnerException:{ex.InnerException}. \nStackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}. \nInnerExceptionMessage:{ex.InnerException?.Message}.");
    }

    return subscribersDetails;
}

public class Subscriber
{
        public string SubscriberCode { get; set; }
        public string SubscriberName { get; set; }
        public string SubscriberEndpoint { get; set; }
        public string TopicName { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public int TopicId { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SubscriberActiveDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SubscriberExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```

`SubscriberCode` column may be NULL or have data. `subscribers` data passed as comma delimiter value.

Case #1: if `subscribers` data is passed, the stored procedure should return matching subscriber details and also where subscrbercode is empty based on topic id and event id

```
exec FetchSubscriberDetails_BasedonTopicEvent @topicid =1,@eventid = 1, @subscribers = '100,200'
```

In above sample all 3 records must return but only SubscriberId=1 and SubcriberId=2 records are coming in c# but not SubscriberId =3

Case #2: if `subscribers` data is not passed, only subscrbercode empty records should return based on topic id and event id.

```
exec FetchSubscriberDetails_BasedonTopicEvent @topicid =1,@eventid = 1, @subscribers = ''
```

In above example, only 1 record with SubscriberId = 3 row data should return.

This is working fine in Azure SQL when executing but when running with C# code, I am not getting proper records where subscribercode is NULL.

The C# code should return SubscriberId = 3 record which is not happening.

Expected output for case #2:

```
SubscriberId -- 3
SubscriberCode -- NULL
Subscriber Name --  Wipro
ActiveDate --   01-01-2022
ExpiryDate  -- NULL
Endpoint --     https://..3
TopicId --  1
EventId --  1
```

Actual output of case #2:

```
No records found
```

I tried replacing `NULL` with blank empty text in row data. This also does not help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"I am not getting NULL records where subscribercode is NULL"* - do you mean this by way of observing that you don't see `null` in `subscriber.SubscriberCode`?

Comment: @madreflection No, I am not at all getting SubscriberId =3 record in c#

Comment: Then purely as an aside or a review note (rather than an answer), using `Convert` methods is almost always wrong. `Convert.ToString` converts NULL (`DBNull.Value`) to an empty string. So when you do get rows that contain NULLs, they won't be `null` in your properties. Don't mangle your data. Use `reader.GetString`, and use `reader.IsDbNull` to check for NULL beforehand.

Comment: @madreflection I am  not bothered about ```null``` properties, I am bothered on entire record itself is not getting using ```SqlDataReader```

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying that once you get the *rows* you want, the values will be mangled because you're mangling them by using `Convert.ToString`. Like I said, it was a review note.

Comment: Are you sure you are not hitting an Exception? The catch block does set the return value to null and swallows the exception. If your logger is not functioning it would appear to you that nothing was returned when an Exception was thrown.

Comment: @Igor No exceptions I am getting.

Comment: @madreflection Code is not even hitting inside ```while (await reader.ReadAsync())```

Comment: `I am not getting NULL records where subscribercode is NULL` - That is a confusing statement. Can you include what the Expected result is and what the Actual result is? Right now I am reading this as the method is returning the value `null`. Do you mean something else?

Comment: @Igor updated  expected output and actual output in my query

Comment: So the method does produce an empty `List<Subscriber>` or does it return `null`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247350/discussion-between-pavankumar-gvvs-and-igor).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for reminding will remove ```sp_```

Comment: Another slight detour...http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: If s.SubscriberCode is NULL, `s.SubscriberCode IS NULL OR s.SubscriberCode = '' 
            OR s.SubscriberCode IN (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@subscribers, ',')))` will evaluate to NULL and no records will match.
You should use `ISNULL(s.SubscriberCode, '') = '' OR ISNULL(s.SubscriberCode, '') IN (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@subscribers, ','))`

Comment: @grahamj42 Thanks , This really helped me. I am now getting proper results.

Comment: `if (await reader.ReadAsync())` is definitely wrong, it means you always lose the first row. That is most likely your main issue. There are other problems: the reader needs a `using`, and why do you have `DISTINCT` anyway? And `Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberCode")))` is overly complex when you can just do `(string)reader["SubscriberCode"]`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, You are right , If am using that , I am not getting 1st record.  I removed and used async or sync reading , I am getting all records.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of flaws in your code

- Needs a `using`

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

- Also needs a `using`

```cs
var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

- Specify your parameters types and lengths/precision explicitly

```cs
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@subscribers", subscribers.Trim());
```

Instead do

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@subscribers", SqlDbType.NVarchar, -1).Value = subscribers.Trim();
```

- **This is your primary issue.** This should not be there at all, it is causing you to always skip the first row.

```cs
if (await reader.ReadAsync())
```

- This one is fiendishly complex, completely not necessary

```cs
Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SubscriberCode")))
```

Instead do this

```cs
(string)reader["SubscriberCode"]
```

Or if you might get a null do this

```cs
reader["SubscriberCode"] as string
```

---

Ideally you wouldn't use a comma-separated list at all. Instead use a Table Valued Parameter.

First define a table type. I keep a few standard ones.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList AS TABLE (value nvarchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchSubscriberDetails_BasedonTopicEvent]
    @eventid int,
    @topicid int,
    @subscribers dbo.StringList READONLY,
    @noSubscriber bit
AS 
BEGIN

    /** Fetching Subscriber Details for all Subscribers based on Topic and Event**/
   SELECT DISTINCT  
       s.SubscriberCode, s.SubscriberName,
       s.SubscriberActiveDate, s.SubscriberExpiryDate,
       s.SubscriberEndpoint
   FROM
       [dbo].[MessageSubscribers] s 
   WHERE 
       s.TopicId = @topicid 
       AND s.EventId = @eventid
       AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN s.SubscriberActiveDate AND ISNULL(s.SubscriberExpiryDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
       AND (@noSubscriber = 1
            OR s.SubscriberCode IN (SELECT [value] FROM @subscribers);
```

You use it in C# like this:

```cs
var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
    {"value", typeof(string)}
} };
foreach (var subscriber in SomeSubscriberList)
    table.Rows.Add(subscriber);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@subscribers", SqlDbType.Structured) {
    TypeName = "dbo.StringList",
    Value = table
});
```

Also why use `DISTINCT`, what does it get you? Why do you have duplicates in the first place.

Comment: ```CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList (value nvarchar(100)``` is this syntax correct and what about ```@noSubscriber``` . can you let me know its purpose, just want to know.If i pass as 1 or 0, what differs?

Comment: ```@subscribers dbo.StringList readonly``` Should use readonly

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS Fixed that now, it should be `CREATE TYPE ... AS TABLE`. @noSubScriber is because you cannot do `WHERE @subscribers IS NULL` on a table valued parameter, it doesn't work. So you need a separate parameter to say "ignore the TVP"